# Static grid with dynamic data on button click in extjs4

Tags: extjs4

I'm trying to display different data (from different store and model) deponding on button click but failing at some point ( to be frank, I'm not sure how to use the reconfigure function). Below is my code:

Components and button click function:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    height: 328,
    width: 478,
    title: 'My Panel',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Button1'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Button2',
                    listeners: {
                        click: {
                            fn: me.onButtonClick,
                            scope: me
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Button3'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    id: 'myGrid',
                    title: 'My Grid Panel',
                    store: 'Button1Store',
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'Name',
                            text: 'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'Email',
                            text: 'Email'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        //alert("button 2");

        var gridVar = Ext.getCmp('myGrid');
        var newStore = Ext.getCmp('MyStore2');
        //alert( gridVar.columns[0].dataIndex);
        //gridVar.bindStore(newStore);
        gridVar.reconfigure(newStore, gridVar.columns);
    }

});
```

Store1 and Model 1:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Button1Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Button1Model'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'MyApp.model.Button1Model',
            storeId: 'MyStore1',
            data: [
                {
                    Name: '1',
                    Email: 'test1'
                },
                {
                    Name: '2',
                    Email: 'test2'
                },

            ]
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Button1Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    idProperty: 'Button1Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'Name'
        },
        {
            name: 'Email'
        }
    ]
});
```

Store 2 and Model 2:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Button2Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Button2Model'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            model: 'MyApp.model.Button2Model',
            storeId: 'MyStore2',
            data: [
                {
                    Name: '3',
                    Email: 'test3'
                },
                {
                    Name: '4',
                    Email: 'test4'
                }
            ]
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Button2Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'Name'
        },
        {
            name: 'Email'
        }
    ]
});
```

When I try this, the title and data in the grid dissappears. I tried the `gridVar.bindStore(newStore);` but it throwed an error stating that data is null or undefined. Pls help...

Comment: getCmp returns you a component. Not sure what you mean about not knowing how to use reconfigure. Just pass it a new store instance, Would suggest you read the docs, there's plenty of examples.

Comment: Hi..I had tried 'Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup()' as well..but the same result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using same grid for all actions then change the store's proxy URL for various actions and populate the data to grid by using load() method !!

Comment: Hi..Thanks a lot for the tip and it worked fine. The code in the button onClick I used is `var gridVar = Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getView();
var store = gridVar.getStore();
store.getProxy().url = 'data/Button2Data.json'; 
gridVar.store.load();`. I need a few clarifications as well. Here I have the column and the data index as the same. But If I have to display different number of columns, will this solution help there as well...

Comment: While using load() use a callback function so that you can handles success and failure. Inside success you can write your custom logic. Can you plz elaborate what you are trying to do with the coulmns on various actions